# Why getLast method doesn't work for List in maven?

Tags: java, list, maven

This simple code is failing on the build stage on maven-project.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 2, 3);
        a.getLast();
    }
}
```

With an error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getLast()
location: variable a of type java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
```

If I use ctrl+click on getLast I can find this method in List:

```
default E getLast() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        return this.get(this.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Moreover, if I run this code without maven everything is ok.

I'm using:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.8

Java version: 21

Windows 11 (10.0)
```

Comment: Do you specify the Java version in your pom file?

Comment: You right, that was the problem. In pom java version was 20. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like maven is trying to build your code with the wrong Java version. The Java version that maven uses can be set inside your project's `pom.xml` file. Make sure that the pom file specifies a Java version that supports the features you are using.